# Finite-dimensional faithful representation of a matrix algebra is completely reducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am reading "Noncommutative Geometry and Particle Physics" by van Suijlekom. I have somequestions about the finite representations of matrix algebras.

It was said that any finite-dimensional faithful representation $\mathcal{H}$ of a matrix algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is completely reducible, i.e. a direct sum of irreducible representations. I know that $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ has the up to isomorphism unique irreducible representation $\mathbb{C}^n$. How can I prove the above statement ?

Also later it was mentioned that every finite-dimensional Hilbert-space representation can be written as $\mathcal{H}\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^N \mathbb{C^{n_i}}\otimes V_i$, where the $V_i$ are vector spaces. I was expecting only the direct sum of the $\mathbb{C}^{n_i}$. Why do the tensor products with vector spaces occur?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a silly question, but "matrix algebra" means "subring of $M_n(\mathbb C)$, yes?

Comment: @rschwieb In this book a matrix algebra was defined as an algebra of the form $\mathfrak{A}=\bigoplus_{i=1}^N M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 3):

> In this book a matrix algebra was defined as an algebra of the form $\mathfrak{A}=\bigoplus_{i=1}^N M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$

> It was said that any finite-dimensional faithful representation $\mathcal H$
> of a matrix algebra $\mathcal A$
> is completely reducible

More is true: what you have defined as a matrix algebra is a subclass of rings called [semisimple rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module#Semisimple_rings) (also see maybe the [Wedderburn-Artin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%E2%80%93Artin_theorem)), and for semisimple rings, *all* modules are direct sums of simple modules, and those modules are what you'd call completely reducible representations for $\mathcal A$.

So as you've defined things, it does not matter if $\mathcal H$ is finite dimensional or faithful.  However, I thought I'd heard this theorem stated with $\mathcal A$ something more relaxed than semisimple algebras, and in that case it *did* depend on those hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the more general fact is true: for any algebra $A$ the algebras $A, Mat_{n}(A)$ has isomorphic category of representations. See [wiki/Morita_equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_equivalence)

Here is the proof in our case. Let $W$ be $Mat_n(F)$ module. Denote by $V$ the vector space of columns of length $n$ as right $Mat_n(F)$ module and by $V'$ the vector space of rows of length $n$ as left $Mat_n(F)$ module.

We have the following isomorphism of $(Mat_n(F), Mat_n(F))$ bimodules:

$$V\otimes_F V'\simeq Mat_n(F).$$

So:

$$W\simeq Mat_n(F)\otimes_{Mat_n(F)} W\simeq (V\otimes_F V')\otimes_{Mat_n(F)} W\simeq V\otimes_F (V'\otimes_{Mat_n(F)} W)\simeq V^{\oplus\dim (V'\otimes_{Mat_n(F)}W)}.$$